# Conditional statement referencing separate rows

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:2], each  = 8), examID = as.character(c(11,11:17, 21:28)), baselineExam = c(rep(c(rbind('bl',c(11,14))), each = 2), c(rep('bl', 4), 21, 21, 24, 24)), examType = c("x", "x", "fu", "fu", "y", "z", "fu", "fu", "x", "x", "y", "z", "fu", "fu", "fu", "fu"), expected_col = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "z", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "z", "z"))

# the first four columns are my original data frame
# the last column shows the expected output.     

    id examID baselineExam examType expected_col
1   a     11           bl        x            x
2   a     11           bl        x            x
3   a     12           11       fu            x
4   a     13           11       fu            x
5   a     14           bl        y            y
6   a     15           bl        z            z
7   a     16           14       fu            y
8   a     17           14       fu            y
9   b     21           bl        x            x
10  b     22           bl        x            x
11  b     23           bl        y            y
12  b     24           bl        z            z
13  b     25           21       fu            x
14  b     26           21       fu            x
15  b     27           24       fu            z
16  b     28           24       fu            z
```

There are different types of longitudinal exams (`examType`) for each subject (`id`). Each exam has its unique identifier (`examID`). Only the baseline exam contains the information of the Examtype. 
Follow up exams only contain the information 'fu', but not the correct examType. However, the `baselineExam` column shows which was the baseline exam for the respective follow up. I would like to have a column with the correct examType in each row.  (see `expected_col` in the data frame)

I am stuck. I can't use something like `if(baselineExam %in% examID)` in combination with `any`, because there is no group based on which I can separate those exams.

A way would be to get the index of the row of the respective 'fu', look up which value this is in 'baselineExam' and then look for this number in 'examID' in order to get the examType of this row.

I tried a helper column with the index number (there must be a better way too), and I can get the value for the baseline exam in this row - but I don't know how to then conditionally get the value in examType, when examID (of the baseline-row) == baselineExam (of the follow up row).

base R solutions or dplyr preferred, but open for anything

---

*edit*

I have changed the given data because my previous sample data did not fully reflect the complexity of the real data (I oversimplified it). Unfortunately, neither @www nor @akrun 's solution worked therefore - my bad, because I haven't provided a good enough sample :(
There can be multiple rows per exam ID (long data, rows 1 and 2 in my example), and multiple baseline exams after another before the follow up exams were taken.

Comment: How about a `data.table` solution? This sort of thing is crying out for an update join.

Comment: @thelatemail I have kind of suspected so. I just simply have never really used data.table and am more familiar and proficient with dplyr, which is a bit of a lousy reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using the `dplyr` and the `tidyr` package. the key is to replace `fu` with `NA` and then use the `fill` function to fill in the `NA` with the previous row. `mutate_if` is just converting factor column to a character column. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(examType %in% "fu", NA, examType)) %>%
  fill(type)
dat2
#   id examID baselineExam examType type
# 1  a     11           bl        x    x
# 2  a     12           11       fu    x
# 3  a     13           bl        y    y
# 4  a     14           13       fu    y
# 5  b     21           bl        x    x
# 6  b     22           21       fu    x
# 7  b     23           bl        z    z
# 8  b     24           23       fu    z
```

#### Update

We can use the `dplyr` package to achieve this. First, subset the data frame with known `examType`, find the rows with the unique combination between `id`, `examID`, and `examType`, join the table to the original data frame, and use `coalesce` to combine information.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  filter(!examType %in% "fu") %>%
  distinct(id, examID, examType) %>%
  rename(Type = examType) %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = c("id", "baselineExam" = "examID")) %>%
  mutate(Type = coalesce(Type, examType))

dat2
#    id examID baselineExam examType Type
# 1   a     11           bl        x    x
# 2   a     11           bl        x    x
# 3   a     12           11       fu    x
# 4   a     13           11       fu    x
# 5   a     14           bl        y    y
# 6   a     15           bl        z    z
# 7   a     16           14       fu    y
# 8   a     17           14       fu    y
# 9   b     21           bl        x    x
# 10  b     22           bl        x    x
# 11  b     23           bl        y    y
# 12  b     24           bl        z    z
# 13  b     25           21       fu    x
# 14  b     26           21       fu    x
# 15  b     27           24       fu    z
# 16  b     28           24       fu    z
```

#### Data for the updated example

```
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:2], each  = 8), 
                  examID = as.character(c(11,11:17, 21:28)), 
                  baselineExam = c(rep(c(rbind('bl',c(11,14))), each = 2), c(rep('bl', 4), 21, 21, 24, 24)), 
                  examType = c("x", "x", "fu", "fu", "y", "z", "fu", "fu", "x", "x", "y", "z", "fu", "fu", "fu", "fu"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Maybe you can update a zoo:: na.locf :-) too lazy to post an answer . :-)

Comment: @Wen Thanks. I will update my post when I have time.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `fill` and this seems interesting. It seems a very good solution for my sample problem, but might not work with my real data, where I have many rows per exam. I realise that I should have specified this in the question. I will try with this way and if it does not work will update the question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Apologies for the misleading sample :(

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not know `coalesce`. Very great idea to first find the unique combinations and use this information.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to group by 'id' and create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of 'bl', create the 'type' as the 'examType' that corresponds to 'bl' in 'baselineExam'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id, grp = cumsum(baselineExam == 'bl')) %>% 
    mutate(type = examType[baselineExam == 'bl']) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  id    examID baselineExam examType type 
#  <fct> <fct>  <fct>        <fct>    <fct>
#1 a     11     bl           x        x    
#2 a     12     11           fu       x    
#3 a     13     bl           y        y    
#4 a     14     13           fu       y    
#5 b     21     bl           x        x    
#6 b     22     21           fu       x    
#7 b     23     bl           z        z    
#8 b     24     23           fu       z
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a super interesting way to use `cumsum` and it's probably the way to go, somewhat seems safer than @www ' s answer. However, as before, my example was unfortunately not good enough. This does not account for the cases when the follow up exam does not immediately follow the baseline exam. I will update my data.

Comment: @Tjebo  Your new updated example still gives me the expected output.  May be, that example needs to be changed

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not give the expected output. E.g, rows 7:8 and 13:14 differ